# Changing the status of an order in Magento 2 via the REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento

Does anyone know how to change the status of an existing order in Magento 2 via the REST API?  We are interfacing order status back to Magento via the REST API from a .net application (we are using JSON.net).  I'm able to create shipments, invoice items on the order, and even create credit memos, but I can't seem to change the order status.

Our customer service people use the Magento admin in the call center for order entry and answering customer questions over the phone.  Having the correct order status displayed it very important for them.

Thanks in advance.

Bruce

Comment: did you find a solution? @unashamedvbguy